# How to replace space between a number with comma using SQL Server?

Tags: t-sql

```
SELECT REPLACE('245 289 252 722 265,420 (22,791) (23,482) (24,662)', '^[0-9]', ',')
```

Raw Result      : `245 289 252 722 265,420 (22,791) (23,482) (24,662)`

Need Result     : `245,289 252,722 265,420 (22,791) (23,482) (24,662)`

Answer (score 1):

I assume this question is being asked with the assumption that the data is in a given, particular, and consistent format (otherwise this formatting is pointless). Below is shown an implementation providing the desired results:

```
SELECT
  STUFF(
    (
      SELECT 
        CASE WHEN (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) % 2 = 0) AND LEFT([value], 1) <> '(' AND RIGHT([value], 1) <> ')' THEN CONCAT(',', value) 
        ELSE CONCAT(' ', value) END 
      FROM 
        STRING_SPLIT('245 289 252 722 265,420 (22,791) (23,482) (24,662)', ' ') 
      FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 
    1, 
    1, 
    ''
  ) AS [value]
```

Input: `245 289 252 722 265,420 (22,791) (23,482) (24,662)`

Output: `245,289 252,722 265,420 (22,791) (23,482) (24,662)`

Compatibility level `130` must be set in order to use `STRING_SPLIT`

Comment: @PatrickPangilinan Not a problem. If this solved your question you should mark it as the answer. Otherwise your question will continue to appear in the "Unanswered" feed of questions.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace space with a comma. To deal with commas between parenthesis, use another replace:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE('245 289 252 722 265,420 (22,791) (23,482) (24,662)', ' ', ','), '),(', ') (')
```

Result:

```
 245,289,252,722,265,420,(22,791) (23,482) (24,662)
```

Comment: the result is wrong like this 245,289,252,722,265,420,(22,791),(23,482),(24,662) there is no comma between parentheses

Comment: sorry I but your answer is wrong I need like this 245,289 252,722 265,420 (22,791) (23,482) (24,662)

Comment: Why is there a comma between 245 and 289 and not between 289 and 252? Are all numbers without parenthesis 6 digit numbers?

Comment: those are number or integer must separate by a comma

Comment: You have these 4 groups of numbers: 245 289 252 722 How do you know that this is two 6-digit numbers and not one 3-digit and one 9-digit number?Or four 3-digit numbers. If numbers can vary in size, it is impossible to tell where one ends and the next one begins. I assumed that a space represents the end of a number. If that is not the case, this may be impossible to solve.

Comment: how like this result 245,289 252 722 265 420 (22,791) (23,482) (24,662) the comma from the left side

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't help.